# ELASTICLUSTER How to generate a custom inventory

Tags: docker, ansible, openstack

Hey guys I couldn't find any answer to this. So I have dealing with [elasticluster](https://github.com/elasticluster/elasticluster) + **Ansible** and **OpenStack**, but I got couple problems with it where some of them I have been able to solve  couple of them and some other no. I want to share how I was able to solve the problem working around with the inventory because it is not documented anywhere.

I have this configuration file, it is pretty much from the official [documentation](https://elasticluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). At this point everything is great and it works. However, how about if we don't want to use the default playbook. That is fine because in the documentation is explained how to change that file by just add `playbook_path=newPath`, but it start complaining about the variables, the scripts and then you have to copy pretty much everything from EC to your custom playbook.

Another problem was the inventory file. If you check these config that I have here it has two nodes with `slurm_worker` then in my playbooks I can use it to executes my task, but how about if I want to run some roles for one of those nodes lets say `connection_node`?.

```
# The cloud section defines all properties needed to connect to a specific cloud provider.
# You can define as many cloud sections you want, assuming you have access to different cloud providers and want to deploy different clusters in different clouds. The mapping between cluster and cloud provider is done in a cluster section

[cloud/openstack]
provider=openstack
build_timeout=600
identity_api_version=3
availability_zone=XXXXX


# This section contains information on how to access the instances started on the cloud, including the user and the SSH keys to use.
# Some of the values depend on the image you specified in the cluster section. Values defined here also can affect the setup section and the way the system is setup.
[login/userconfig]
image_user=username
image_sudo=True
image_user_sudo=xxxxxx
user_key_name=XXXXXX
user_key_private={path of the private key file}
user_key_public={path of the public key file}


# This section contain information on how to setup a cluster. After the cluster is started, elasticluster will run a setup provider in order to configure it.
# A setup section is mostly independent of any other, and can be easily re-used across multiple clouds and base OS images – that’s the whole point of ElastiCluster!

[setup/slurm]
provider=ansible
playbook_path=elasticluster/share/playbooks/slurm_cluster.yml
client_groups=slurm_client
master_groups=slurm_master
frontend_groups=slurm_worker
connection_groups=slurm_worker


## Updating elasticluster variables
global_var_ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
global_var_multiuser_cluster=yes
# Version of SLURM to install. Only used on RHEL/CentOS 7
global_var_slurm_version=20.02


# A cluster section defines a “template” for a cluster. This section has references to each one of the other sections and define the image to use, the default number of compute nodes and the security group.

[cluster/projectname]
cloud=openstack
flavor=m3.xsmall
login=userconfig
setup=slurm
image_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
network_ids=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
security_group=default
# Nodes
master_nodes=1
client_nodes=1
worker_nodes=2
connection_nodes=2
ssh_to=master
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need different configuration because that is the logic that I have and I need to install some applications that shouldn't go in one node.

Solving the problem with the custom playbook wast mounting it with docker. What I did was to copy the `main.yml` file and delete what I don't need and then mount it as a volume with docker and my custom roles that I want to run. That works great!!.

Elasticluster by default creates an inventory file with groups `slurm_worker, slurm_client & slurm_master` and here is my problem. How about if I have more VMs that you want to run some roles for each of them? You have to use `slurm_worker` but some hosts in that group you don't want to run your custom-roles.

To solve this, I notice that when you run your `elasticluster setup` it will create the inventory so it is possible to modified it or create your custom one as is explained [here](https://github.com/elasticluster/elasticluster/issues/663), but I didn't like that it is not quite right.

I notice that distributed playbooks that does not exists in EC are ignored as per the doc explain it. Then, what happen if I add new nodes in the config file, EC creates my custom inventory file automatically that is great!!

```
....
.
.

[setup/slurm]
provider=ansible
playbook_path=elasticluster/share/playbooks/slurm_cluster.yml
client_groups=slurm_client,custom_client
master_groups=slurm_master,custom_master
frontend_groups=slurm_worker,custom_frontend
connection_groups=slurm_worker,custom_connection

.
.
....
```